# Site is calling same file multiple times but doesn't show in code?

Tags: php, html, css, firebug, pagespeed

I am honestly not sure where the issue lays but here is my problem:

I have a single file: card.gif. When I check firebug or Google pagespeed, I learn the file is called twice during the page fetch once as normal file name and a second time with a random number (that does not change). Example:

1. card.gif
2. card.gif?1316720450953

I have scoured my actual source code, the image is only called once. It is not called in a CSS file. To be honest I have no idea what is the issue, some thought that when I originally installed mod_pagespeed that it appended ID's to each image in cache for any future overwrites but I can't be certain.

Has anybody ever had this issue before?

Comment: usually done to avoid caching, what's the page url?

Comment: @dagon - right but unless a script is doing this automatically, there is nowhere on the page calling the file twice nor does it make sense it would deliver the original if this was the case. You will not be able to view the page as it is under development and password protected currently unfortunately. Is there a way in firebug to tell WHERE on the page the call is being made for that resource?

Comment: That looks more like a timestamp than a random number. Probably the file's last modification time?

Comment: web developer>view generated source

Comment: @JM4 my guess is that what's actually happening is a request to `card.gif` is 303'ing to `card.gif?timestamp` (probably due to `mod_pagespeed`), and somehow the OP is interpreting that as 'two requests'.

Comment: @Dagon - no such link, unless you are saying to simply view "Web Developer->Page Source" in which came is the same as right click view source?

Comment: if you have the web developer plug-in, then there is view source and *view generated source*

Comment: @Dagon - got it now. The 'generated source' only shows 1 version of the file and it does in fact contain the timestamp/id mentioned above.

Comment: i would be inclined to trust the source and say those tools are not use to graphics with variables attached.

Answer (score 0):

In the end - Dagon's comments above led me to believe that things like Firebug and Pagespeed may not always be correct. I do show two images being loaded in the timelines for both plugins but it is very difficult for me to decifer otherwise. If another answer is provided contradicting this, I am more than happy to test that theory.